# Flutter - Unable to get intent for global urls in ios

Tags: ios, flutter, share-intent

I am currently developing an Flutter iOS application containing a Share extension.

When trying to share any file from Files getting app in share tray but not getting app when trying to share website urls from safari or youtube links from YouTube.

I have followed all steps for iOS from : https://pub.dev/packages/share_handler and successfully run the code.
**Step 1** : `xCode -> File -> New -> Target -> selected Share Extension` from List and named as "Share Extension"
**Step 2** : `Share Extension/info.plis` 
`<key>NSExtension</key> <dict> <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key> <dict> <key>IntentsSupported</key> <array> <string>INSendMessageIntent</string> </array <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key> <string>SUBQUERY ( extensionItems, $extensionItem, SUBQUERY ( $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment, ( ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.file-url" || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image" || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.text" || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.movie" || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" ) ).@count > 0 ).@count > 0 </string> <key>PHSupportedMediaTypes</key> <array> <string>Video</string> <string>Image</string> </array> </dict> <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key> <string>MainInterface</string> <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key> <string>com.apple.share-services</string> </dict> </dict> </plist>` 
**Step 3** : `Runner/info.plist`
`<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key> <string>To upload photos, please allow permission to access your photo library.</string> <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key> <array> <dict> <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key> <string>Editor</string> <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key> <array> <string>ShareMedia</string> </array> </dict> </array>`
**Step 4 **: added the following code `projectroot/ios/Podfile`
`target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(**FILE**))

## share_handler addition start

target 'ShareExtension' do
inherit! :search_paths
pod "share_handler_ios_models", :path => ".symlinks/plugins/share_handler_ios/ios/Models"
end

## share_handler addition end

end`